# Solve the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laurent-series

> Solve the Dirichlet problem for the Laplace equation in $\Bbb{R}^2$:
>   $$\begin{cases}\Delta u=0&\text{ in } 1<|x|<2\\u=x_1&\text{ on }|x|=1\\u=1+x_1x_2&\text{ on } |x|=2\end{cases}$$

The hint says to use Laurent series.

**Attempt:** We know both boundary polynomials are harmonic ($\Delta x_1=\Delta( 1+x_1 x_2)=0$), so we write a series $u=\sum p_m$ where $p_m$ are harmonic polynomials. This series should go to $x_1$ as $|x|=1$ and $1+x_1 x_2$ for $|x|=2$. So $u=x_1+1+x_1 x_2+\sum p_m$, but I don't know what the rest of the $p_m$ should be.

Any hints? I would prefer hints to full answers.

Answer (score 1):

This one has the full answer. Hidden from view unless you mouse-over

Step 1:

> We can find a harmonic function that is equal to $1$ on $|x| = 2$ and $0$ on $|x| = 1$. To do so we use the ansatz
>   $$ \phi(x) = a \ln |x| + b $$
>  and we see that $a = \frac{1}{\ln 2}$ and $b = 0$ works.

Step 2:

> We can find a harmonic function that is equal to $x_1$ on $|x| = 1$ and $0$ on $|x| = 2$. To do so we use the ansatz
>  $$ \phi(x) = a \frac{x_1}{|x|^2} + b x_1 = x_1 (\frac{a}{|x|^2}  + b) $$
>  and we see that $a + b = 1$ and $a/4 + b = 0$.

Step 3:

> We can find a harmonic function that is equal to $x_1 x_2$ on $|x| = 2$ and $0$ on $|x| = 1$. We proceed with the ansatz
>  $$ \phi(x) = a \partial^2_{x_1x_2} \ln(|x|) + b x_1 x_2 $$
>  and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Explanation:

> In terms of Laurent series, what we are doing is using that $1/z^n$ are holomorphic functions outside the origin, and so their real and imaginary parts are harmonic. In particular, you have that $\frac{1}{z^n} = \frac{\bar{z}^n}{|z|^{2n}}$ the denominator now taking constant values over circles centered at zero. 
>  Note also that $z^n$ also are harmonic functions. 
>  So with two circular boundaries you can take linear combinations between $z^{-n}$ and $z^n$ to get "polynomial-like" boundary values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for hints:

---

**Hint**

Let $v = \ln(|x|)$, then $\partial_{x_1} v$ is a harmonic function (why?) and equals $x_1$ on $|x| = 1$ (why?)

---

Do something similar for $1 + x_1x_2$.

**Another hint**:

The $1$ and the $x_1 x_2$ are not on the same footing in the expression $1 + x_1 x_2$. (In terms of Taylor series at the origin, the first is the 0th order term and the second is the second order term.) Their "Laurent series" partners are therefore also not on the same footing.

---

**Third and final hint**:

This one may give away the answer, so I am hiding it. Don't mouse-over until you are really stuck.

> What we are getting at is the multipole expansion in 2 dimensions. The function $x_1$ is "singular at infinity", as is the function $x_1 x_2$. In fact, the same is true of all harmonic polynomials. They have partners which are "singular at zero" (here's where the Laurent series comes in). We choose zero and infinity as the two singular points since they are "equidistant" from the circular boundaries of your annulus.

Comment: If you are wondering what this has to do with Laurent series: what are the real and imaginary parts of $1 / z^n$ with $z = x + i y$?

Comment: Not quite what I am thinking of. Remember that $v$ is the Newton potential on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so all of its derivatives are harmonic functions. Its first gradient is $1/z$. (There is a reason I asked you to compute $1/z^n$ and not just $1/z$.)

Comment: I can tell this is a very good hint, but I'm completely lost with what you're doing. What does singular at infinity or zero have to do with anything?

Comment: The singularities are the "centers". notice that $\partial_{x_1} v$ has a denominator that is constant on circles. If you try to do the same thing using a potential that is centered other than origin or infinity, you will not get simple polynomials on the boundary. // Don't worry about being confused, there is _a lot_ that can be said about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The general solution of $\ds{2D}$*-Laplace Equation* is given by:
\begin{align}
\Phi\pars{\vec{r}} & =
\pars{A + B\theta}\bracks{C\ln\pars{r} + D}
+ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{A_{n}\sin\pars{n\theta + \phi_{n}}r^{n} +
B_{n}\sin\pars{n\theta + \delta_{n}}{1 \over r^{n}}}
\end{align}
As the boundary conditions are 'quite simple'
$\ds{\pars{~\cos\pars{\theta}\ \mbox{at}\ r = 1\ \mbox{and}\ 1 + 2\sin\pars{2\theta}\ \mbox{at}\ r = 2~}}$ it's sufficient to write:
$$
\Phi\pars{\vec{r}}  =
{\ln\pars{r} \over \ln\pars{2}} + \mrm{b}\pars{r}\cos\pars{\theta} +
2\mrm{c}\pars{r}\sin\pars{2\theta}\,,\qquad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{b}\pars{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{1\,,} & \ds{\mrm{b}\pars{2}} & \ds{=}
&  \ds{0}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\mrm{c}\pars{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0\,,} & \ds{\mrm{c}\pars{2}} & \ds{=}
&  \ds{1}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

$$
\nabla^{2}\phi\pars{\vec{r}} =
\partiald[2]{\phi\pars{\vec{r}}}{r} +
{1 \over r}\,\partiald{\phi\pars{\vec{r}}}{r} +
{1 \over r^{2}}\,\partiald[2]{\phi\pars{\vec{r}}}{\theta}
$$
Note that $\ds{\left.\nabla^{2}\ln\pars{r}\right\vert_{\ r\ >\ 0} = 0}$.

---

$$
\left.\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\partiald[2]{\mrm{b}\pars{\vec{r}}}{r} +
{1 \over r}\,\partiald{\mrm{b}\pars{\vec{r}}}{r} - {\mrm{b}\pars{r} \over r^{2}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\partiald[2]{\mrm{c}\pars{\vec{r}}}{r} +
{1 \over r}\,\partiald{\mrm{c}\pars{\vec{r}}}{r} - {4\mrm{c}\pars{r} \over r^{2}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\end{array}\right\}\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{b}\pars{r}} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\,{1 \over 3}\pars{r - {4 \over r}}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mrm{c}\pars{r}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{4 \over 15}\pars{r^{2} - {1 \over r^{2}}}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
In the OP notation, the solution is given by:
$$\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
\Phi\pars{\vec{r}} =
{\ln\pars{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} \over 2\ln\pars{2}} -
{1 \over 3}\pars{x_{1} - {4x_{1} \over x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}} +
{16 \over 15}\bracks{x_{1}x_{2} - {x_{1}x_{2} \over \pars{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}^{2}}}}}
$$